# Python Requests - response.json() not working as intended

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to call an API from Python's requests module. On postman, the Content-Type in the response headers returned is `application/json; charset=utf-8`, and the response json data is how I'd expect it to look like. However, running `response.json()` after the get method for the API on python throws the error `simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

Hope someone could help explain why this happens.

First few lines of the content returned on Postman:

```
{
    "Pagination": {
        "query": "",
        "index": "PRODUCTION_PG_FEATURED_DESC",
        "limit": "100",
        "page": 1,
        "total": 8556,
        "lastPage": "/api/v3/browse?_tags=adidas&page=10&productCategory=sneakers&resultsPerPage=100",
        "sort": [
            "featured"
        ],
        "order": [
            "DESC"
        ],
        "currentPage": "/api/v3/browse?_tags=adidas&page=1&productCategory=sneakers&resultsPerPage=100",
        "nextPage": "/api/v3/browse?_tags=adidas&page=2&productCategory=sneakers&resultsPerPage=100",
        "previousPage": null
    },
```

My code block:

```
import requests

productsAPI = 'https://stockx.com/api/browse?_tags=nike&productCategory=sneakers&page=1&resultsPerPage=100'
headers = {"accept": "*/*", "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br","User-Agent" :"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36", 
        "Connection" : "keep-alive"}
response = requests.get(productsAPI, headers = headers)
print(response.text)
        
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.status_code)
try: 
    data = response.json()
except:
    print('fail')

print(data["Facets"]["brand"])
```

Comment: Can you show what the content of the response is?

Comment: It's very easy to [Edit] your question. Do not put code / data into comments.

Comment: above json is valid (missing close `}`). if `response.json()` gives error, you can paste  `response.text` here for analysis.

Comment: You are saying "on postman" the response is what you expected, but the error lies with usage of the `request` module, but yet the exact state of the `response` object was not provided.  Please provide the output of relevant fields from the `response` object (e.g. `print(response.text)` or the headers from it), rather than just what your expected output provided from postman.

Comment: Show us your code.  it's too easy to make dumb errors that your eyes won't see.

Comment: Hi, I'm unable to add the response.text, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add it because its encoded, a bunch of hex codes and question marks.

Comment: Well, then it's obviously not JSON.

Comment: @TimRoberts , I see, I'd like to understand why Postman returns Json, even in the raw response

Comment: how do you know postman displays as json, not plain text?

Comment: @LeiYang, I can't tell for sure, but it automatically chooses JSON as the option for the 'Prettier' formatting. Clicking on 'Auto' also chooses JSON as a default

Comment: if this destination site is publicly accessible and no sensitive data, i suggest paste the working requests code here. so we can reproduce lcoally.

Comment: @LeiYang , I've edited the code so you could reproduce it :)

Comment: i tried the code. the response is totally binary, not text, let alone json. there should be some difference between your postman requests and the python.

Comment: @LeiYang, I've checked again, there really aren't any differences in the requests, other than the fact that in postman's auto generated headers, the User-Agent is PostmanRuntime/7.28.1, while mine is as above

Comment: i did some search and found the site **stockx.com/api** is quite popular for web crawlers. among the sdks there's python version [stockx-py-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/stockx-py-sdk/), why not try it out? or you can at least learn something from its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm not sure how you don't see the obvious problem.  You have this header:

```
    "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
```

and the server happily took your suggestion and deflated and gzipped the response.  If you aren't prepared to accept encodings, then for gosh sakes get rid of the line that says you will.  That fixes it.

We could have found this a lot sooner if you had posted your code to begin with.

Comment: remove `accept-encoding` indeed working! but what's the expected value if want json format, not remove the k-v from header?

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks for the reply. It works. Just as a suggestion, I’d really appreciate if you could be a little more patient and less aggressive with the responses. Not everyone’s been coding since Nixon. Was trying my best to understand what the issue was. Also, it wasn’t that obvious as well since postman’s auto generated headers includes accept-encoding, which strayed me away from the answer.

Comment: My reply was not aggressive.  And it is absolutely true that we could have solved this problem hours sooner had you included the code to begin with.  The site's guidelines all clearly state how to ask questions properly.  I've answered tens of thousands of technical questions over the decades, and you can see from my reputation score that I am normally quite patient, but I do sometimes lose that patience when I see mistakes that seem obvious.  And, after all, free advice is worth every penny you paid.  ;)